# Prolog: why does this query not terminate?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and I'm trying to write a rule `upToHalfPrefix(A, B)` that is true if the list A is a prefix of the list B and A's length is no more than half of B's length. This is my attempt:

```
upToHalfPrefix([A|X], [B|Y]) :-
  length([B|Y], N),
  length([A|X], K),
  TwiceK is K*2,
  TwiceK < N,
  prefix([A|X], [B|Y]).
```

but then when I issue the query:

```
6 ?- upToHalfPrefix(P, [0,1,2,3,4]).
P = [0] ;
P = [0, 1] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

... it doesnt stop. What is the reason for this, and how could I fix it or write the rule a different way?

EDIT:
After a bit of reordering, I have a fix:

```
upToHalfPrefix([A|X], [B|Y]) :-
    prefix([A|X], [B|Y]),
    length([B|Y], N),
    length([A|X], K),
    TwiceK is K*2,
    TwiceK < N.
```

Query:

```
9 ?- upToHalfPrefix(P, [0,1,2,3,4]).
P = [0] ;
P = [0, 1] ;
false.
```

My suspicion was the `length([A|X], K)` query where [A|X] is an out result as well as K being an out result is troublesome, but I'm looking for a better explanation.

Comment: It's not just that the arguments are "out" results, but the predicate as originally written could keep retrying different lengths and lists for `length([A|X], K)` when `prefix/2` fails and runs unbounded. When you changed the order, your initial `prefix/2` call bounds the potential results before you get to the `length/2` calls.